# NavBar h1 element stuck on top

Tags: html, css, navbar

I want my nav bar to have the h1 element and li element to stick to the bottom. My h1 element is stuck to the top when I want it to be on the bottom like my li elements. I have the image pasted down below along with the code.

[How the navbar looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji27x.png)

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:block;
  background-color:#abb2bc;
}



.container{


}

#Home{
  font-size:20px;
  display: inline;
  text-align:center;
  
}

main ::after{
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}

.nav{
  background-color: #363b42;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab',serif;


}

.nav a:hover{
  color:#29703f;
  text-decoration: overline;
  font-size:22px;
}


.nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.nav ul{
  margin:0;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  padding:0px;

}

header ::after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}

.nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 75px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align:center;

}

.nav h1{
  float:left;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fortnite Tips</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navigation bar -->
  <header class="container">
    <div class="nav">
      <a><h1 id="Home">GamingCoachBlog</h1></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact<a /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

If you could explain why this isn't working I would appreciate it. I have been stuck on this for a while as I am still learning how to make responsive websites.

Comment: Nothing to do with your bug, but instead of <div class="nav"> you could use the <nav> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make `<h1>` inside `<ul>` like below :

```
<ul>
  <li><a><h1 id="Home">GamingCoachBlog</h1></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact<a /></li>
</ul>
```

and delete this rule in your css `float:left;`

Answer (score 0):

Two issues

1. The space between `header ::after` applies the style after every child element of header.
2. You should clearfix .nav, not the header.

So make it:

```
.nav::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```